# How can I get a checksum of an entire table in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

My java 11+ apache jmeter application throws a certain load (insert,update) into the Postgresql database for load testing.

All changes are replicated to another database, I will have a list of tables for which data changes were made.
After all changes are completed, all tables must be compared to verify that replication is correct.
This can be done as follows:

```
SELECT        
    md5(CAST((array_agg(f.* order by id))AS text)) 
FROM
    foo f;
```

or concatenate all the rows of the table and get a hash from them, but for large tables it will take a long time.
Please tell me if there is a way to do this optimally?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by using parallel hashing.Divide and Conquer -Break large tables into smaller chunks and compute checksums concurrently for better performance.

Sample implementation of parallel hashing you can use:

```
WITH chunks AS (
    SELECT id, md5(CAST((array_agg(f) ORDER BY f.id) AS text)) AS chunk_hash
    FROM foo f
    GROUP BY id % 4
)
SELECT md5(CAST(array_agg(chunk_hash) AS text)) FROM chunks;
```

Hope this helps.